# Twilio python MessagingResponse.message.media not working for a mp3 audio

Tags: python, xml, twilio, whatsapp

```
@app.route('/bot', methods=['POST'])
def bot():

    content = request.form.get('Body').lower()

    resp = MessagingResponse()
    msg = resp.message()

    responded = False

    if 'hi' in content:
        msg.media(url_for('static', filename='bonjour.mp3'), content_type='audio/mpeg')
        responded = True
    if not responded:
        msg.body('no')
    return str(resp)
```

That's my code to respond to a Whatsapp message. If you say 'hi', it should send you an mp3 audio that i saved (I checked that the path is correct), and if you say something else it just says 'no'. But when I send a message with 'hi', I get this error in the Twilio debug part :
[error 12200](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XDVB9.png)

Comment: The URL you pass to `media()` needs to be an absolute URL of a media file which is publicly available, not a relative one. In your case _not_ `/static/bonjour.mp3` but something like `https://yourdomain.com/static/bonjour.mp3`. Also omit the `content_type`.

Comment: Oh ok thank you @yvesonline but to do that i should make another `@app.route`?

Comment: I don't know your setup so whatever you do to serve static files. I personally use S3 storage buckets. Make sure to first test it with an `mp3` file somewhere publicly available. I'll convert my comment in a proper answer in a minute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The URL you pass to `media()` needs to be an absolute URL of a media file which is publicly available, not a relative one.

In your case not `/static/bonjour.mp3` but something like `https://yourdomain.com/static/bonjour.mp3`.

Also omit the `content_type`.